# Landing / Static HTML page

Tags: homepage, customization

I want to use static HTML for a landing page on a WordPress site. For example:

- `example.com` - WordPress already running in root folder
- `landingPage.example.com` - I purchased this static landing page using
  ThemeForest

Answer (score 4):

Just name the landing page file `index.html` and place it (and any assets) in the root directory, then add this to your `.htaccess` (assuming you're using Apache):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

When accessing `http://example.com`, Apache will serve `index.html`. WordPress will scoop up all other requests with it's rewrite rules.

Comment: Great idea. Saves a lot of work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your **hosting cpanel**
2. Go to **domains** section
3. Create a **sub domain** for your `(example.com)` domain
4. Enter the name of the domain `landingpage`

After creating sub domain it will add `landingPage` folder in the root of your hosting filemanager. place the template there and it will be accessed through `landingPage.example.com`

Answer (score -1):

1. extract the template's files and rename the index.html file to index.php
2. add all the files to a .ZIP archive again
3. create a new empty folder in the root folder of your WordPress website and upload your .ZIP file into the folder you’ve just created
4. unzip them and don't forget to delete the .ZIP file

Source with screenshots: http://www.templatemonster.com/blog/integrate-static-html-wordpress/