# How to use custom Html file instead of wordpress homepage

Tags: homepage

I have wordpress installed in root folder of domain.com

I want to load index.html when domain.com is visited and domain.com/my-posts/ should load normal wordpress posts.

I am doing this to increase speed of my wordpress homepage.I dont want any php to be involved.

Will renaming index.php to index.html and putting my html content will work ?

Comment: A more constructive answer is to have this file somewhere and add a rewrite rule that will serve it when the home page is requested/ Place that rule before the wordpress rules

Comment: You'd do that with a page-template:      https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: Question is not silly , What if i need custom html landing page using bootstrap as homepage ? AndI dont want 1.3 mb page to load :p

Comment: Gracie, PHP runs on the server and is one of the very least concerns for page speed optimization.  A thousand lines of PHP code could execute in the time it takes a browser to request a single image asset for your page.  Unless your situation is an edge case of some kind, the performance benefit to be gained here is not worth your effort IMO.

Comment: @Graciewilliams, if you use bootstrap, it will take much more time in vanilla HTML to load all the assets of bootstrap than for wordpress running on a proper server configuration to generate the page dynamically, and if you care about performance you will use CDN, which means that you already have caching. Anyway, landing page is a great example why it is wrong, aren't you going to want to use a plugin for that page (SEO, contact form, etc), are you realy going to "manually" change every little thing when needed instead of using the power of a CMS?

Comment: ok wat if only pure css , js and html ? I didnt mean literally , just example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I **strongly** advise you to heed the advice already given. If your PHP is well structured and you take advantage of caching methods, it won't have a significant increase on your page load time. We've got pages with extremely complex queries that are hardly optimized, but using some clever caching methods, we're able to get those pages served in 500-900ms, or 2-3s for some of the much more complex pages.

It's a much better long term solution than using a static HTML page as your homepage.

*That said* - if you still wish to proceed with a static HTML homepage instead (again, please don't, **especially** if the only reason is "page speed", since there are so many other ways to decrease your page load time)

... Still reading?

## Method 1: .htaccess

The… … "generally accepted" way to do this is with a `.htaccess` rule that targets your homepage only, such as `RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/path-to-html.html [L,R=301]`

## Method 2: Page Template

Alternatively, to maintain *some* semblance to the WordPress ecosystem would be to set up a [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

- Add a `home.php` (yes, PHP file) to your active theme directory: `/wp-content/themes/CURRENT-THEME/home.php`.
- Place the following "Page Template Header" code in that file (leave a note to your future self/fellow devs that say where the file is so it's less confusing):

  ```
  <?php
      /*
       * Template Name: My HTML Homepage
       */
  ?>
  <!-- This page is generated outside of WP by: /wp-content/themes/CURRENT-THEME/home.php -->
  <!-- Your HTML Code Here -->
  ```
- Add a new Page with **Pages** > **Add New** with a recognizable name, such as "My HTML Homepage"
- On the right hand side, in the **Template** selector, choose "My HTML Homepage" as the template.
- In **Settings** > **Reading** change "Your Homepage Displays:" to "A Static Page", and pick the "My HTML Homepage" page you just added.

## Method 3: Move your WordPress Install

You can also just install WordPress on a subdirectory, have `index.html` in the root directory, and use .htaccess to remove the /wp from your URLs.

## Method 4: Don't.

Again, I **strongly** urge you to consider other methods:

- Taking advantaged of PHP 7.x and memcache/d
- Caching plugins like WP Super Cache/W3 Total Cache
- Optimizing your images (manually or with WP Smush)

  - Serve images from a CDN
- Optimizing Script/Style delivery (WP Hummingbird can help with this):

  - Combine files where appropriate/able
  - Minify those files
  - Serve those files from a CDN
- Remove unnecessary plugins from WP, optimize JS functions, remove unused CSS selectors, etc.

Comment: I have nginx , Wp super cache and total cache is not working fine with it.

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials and other docs out there on setting up WPSC with Nginx. Alternatively you could also consider a PHP plugin like [PHPFastCache](http://www.phpfastcache.com/). Also, make sure you're taking advantage of the [WP Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), especially for expensive queries.

Comment: Note that WP will automatically use the `home.php` template for the homepage if it's in the theme, all this extra stuff about pages and page template headers and going into settings is completely unnecessary unless you want to make the homepage editable in a page builder or store things against a page

Answer (score 3):

If your concern is that PHP or MySQL is causing the page load speed to decrease, I recommend installing a Caching plugin and configuring Page Caching. A free plugin that I've used for this purpose is [W3 Total Cache](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

Page caching essentially does what you are looking for, which is to serve a static HTML file with CSS and Javascript assets, instead of running PHP and MySQL queries whenever a page is loaded.

It does this by pre-generating each page as a static HTML file, and then serves those static files in place of the dynamic PHP / MySQL Wordpress engine.

It's much easier to set up than having to manage a separate static HTML file for your landing page.

Comment: side note: from my experience  W3TC is an undebuggble POS. I get it that you had better mileage with it then me, but I felt the need to drop here a note that there are other plugins that might be better

Comment: its not working fine for me in nginx , same speed in pagespeed insights

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple approach to this using index.html.  You can add your index.html landing page and then you simply need to define that as your landing page in your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

This will force your home landing page to the index.html page and let WP do all the rest of the heavy lifting.

I'm sure there are lots of other reasons for the good advice above, but  I needed a simple landing page to take over the built in redirect and user management functions of an intranet theme.

Answer from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211630/64947

Answer (score 0):

Another method if you're using Apache is to name your index file something special and prepend that name to your DirectoryIndexes. For example:

1. Save your static index file as `index-static.html`
2. Open `httpd.conf` and edit the `DirectoryIndex` list

   ```
   <IfModule dir_module>
     DirectoryIndex index-static.html index.php index.html
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Save `httpd.conf` and run `sudo service httpd restart`

Compared to Method 1 in the previous answer, this method has the benefit of not modifying your homepage URL — that is, visitors won't see `static-index.html` appended to the domain when they visit your site because no redirect occurs. This is probably better for SEO purposes in addition to being transparent to visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this - paste this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This code will redirect your index.php file and load it in the browser. If you’ve used a case-sensitive name for the folder or any of the files it will also work to redirect them and show you their contents.